# VGA-output for iPad

Tags: ipad

I am a newbie I am making an iPad game and I just bought the VGA-output cable provided by apple. I want my game to be VGA-output supported but I dont have any idea how to do it. I have used cocos2D to create my game.

How can I make my game VGA-output supported (I couldn't find and information in the forums)?
What piece of code do I have to add?

Thanks for help guys. I really appreciate it.

Jay

Answer (score 0):

It's supported by the UIScreen class, official documentation here:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html